# Custom class not displaying components on screen Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a custom component for flash using AS3, but when i create an instance of my class and add it to the stage nothing is displayed on the screen. I just can't seem to figure it out...

What I have is a class that extends MovieClip, and contains a couple textField components for which i set the text and then call addChild(tfn); but nothing...

Any help much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
package com.utils {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

public class LeaderBoardLoader extends MovieClip {

    // components
    public var txtPosition:TextField;
    public var thumbHolder:MovieClip;
    public var container:MovieClip;
    public var txtName:TextField;
    public var txtVotes:TextField;
    public var btnViewVid:Button;
    public var imgLoader:Loader;

    // text styling
    public var myFormat:TextFormat;  
    public var myFormat2:TextFormat;
    public var myFormat3:TextFormat;

    public function LeaderBoardLoader(position:String, imageURL:String, pers:String, votes:String, vidURL:String) 
    {
        txtPosition = new TextField();
        thumbHolder = new MovieClip();
        txtName = new TextField();
        txtVotes = new TextField();
        btnViewVid = new Button();
        container = new MovieClip();
        myFormat = new TextFormat();
        myFormat2 = new TextFormat();
        myFormat3 = new TextFormat();
        imgLoader = new Loader();
        trace("started");

        //Giving the format a hex decimal color code  
        myFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;   
        //Adding some bigger text size  
        myFormat.size = 16;  
        //Giving the format a hex decimal color code  
        myFormat2.color = 0xFFFFFF;   
        //Adding some bigger text size  
        myFormat2.size = 11;  
        //Giving the format a hex decimal color code  
        myFormat3.color = 0xEF0000;   
        //Adding some bigger text size  
        myFormat3.size = 10;  
        trace("started");
        container.width = 500;
        container.height = 50;



        txtPosition.x = 0;
        txtPosition.y = 0;
        txtPosition.text = position + ".";
        txtPosition.setTextFormat(myFormat);
        trace("started1");
        //imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageURL));
        imgLoader.width = 60;
        imgLoader.height = 60;
        thumbHolder.addChild(imgLoader);
        thumbHolder.x = 20;
        thumbHolder.y = 0;
        trace("started2");
        txtName.text = pers;
        txtName.x = 100;
        txtName.y = 10;
        txtName.setTextFormat(myFormat2);
        trace("started3");
        txtVotes.text = votes;
        txtVotes.x = 100;
        txtVotes.y = 20;
        txtVotes.setTextFormat(myFormat2);
        trace("started4");
        btnViewVid.textField.text = "VIEW VIDEO";
        btnViewVid.textField.setTextFormat(myFormat3);
        btnViewVid.x = 200;
        btnViewVid.y = 20;
        btnViewVid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewVideo);
        addChild(txtPosition);
        addChild(thumbHolder);
        addChild(txtName);
        addChild(txtVotes);
        addChild(btnViewVid);


    }


    function viewVideo(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("hulo light");            

    }




}

}
```

All the traces and no compiler errors....

Comment: This might not fix it, but after looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298284/textformat-doesnt-do-anything), I think you want to set the `defaultTextFormat` property manually instead of calling `setTextFormat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Main class :

```
var displayTest:MovieClip = new LeaderBoardLoader("tavu", "bump.jpg", "kevin", "12");
addChild(displayTest);
```